In Dash can I update an output value but disable further updates from that change?
I have two inputs, and an output. Both inputs, when changed, affect the output.
When the user types a value in one input, I want the value in the other to be cleared...but to NOT invoke the follow-on callback that would update the output. Is this possible?
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id="foo"),
    dcc.Input(id="bar"),
    html.Div(id="out")
])

@callback(
    Output("out", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    Output("bar", "value"),   # changing this shouldn't trigger from_bar
    Input("foo", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def from_foo(value: str):
   return (f"foo={value}", "")

@callback(
    Output("out", "children", allow_duplicate=True),
    Output("foo", "value"),  # changing this shouldn't trigger from_foo
    Input("bar", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def from_bar(value: str):
   return (f"bar={value}", "")

I know there's a solution in simple cases where you put all the inputs and outputs into a single callback and then use callback_context to pick which changed and modify your logic and use dash.no_update to not change that one. But I'm directly asking if there's a way to set a flag or something that says "skip callbacks when processing the outputs just of this function".

what happens if the inputs are 1 and 2, and I delete the number 1, but then type 1 back?
